# Google applications unreachable in Chrome/IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, gmail, google-workspace

As of today, when I try to go to https://gmail.com, I get the following error:
[image: google error message]

I am not sure if I have been compromised somehow or what.  This is happening in Chrome and IE, not in Firefox.  Any ideas?

Error text for crawls:

> Cannot connect to the real www.gmail.com
>
> Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to
>   www.gmail.com.
>
> Try to reload this page in a few minutes or after switching to a new
>   network. If you have recently connected to a new Wi-Fi network, finish
>   logging in before reloading.
>
> If you were to visit www.gmail.com right now, you might share private
>   information with an attacker. To protect your privacy, Chrome will not
>   load the page until it can establish a secure connection to the real
>   www.gmail.com.

Comment: This is Chrome verifying the SSL certificate of its websites.  Where is your network connection coming from?  Could someone have an SSL proxy on the network?

Comment: So before today it worked as expected with the same computer, settings and network you're using today?

Comment: If you are getting this message you should trust the warning.  Chrome will verify the Google certificates are real.  If you are getting this message it means Chrome believes your certificates are invalid.

Answer (score 6):

Please verify that the time on your computer is correct.

Just to be safe, go ahead and sync it to your timezone. Alot of these issues are easy fixes, because the time somehow got messed up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to WreithKassan's answer, There are two other less-likely possibilities:

1. You're behind a captive portal, and it is attempting to redirect you to a login page of some sort
2. Your root-certificate store has become corrupted.  This can be the result of a virus or simple data-corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not on a hotel or corporate WiFi hotspot that may have a "captive portal" login mechanism, your DNS or Proxy settings may have been tampered with (possibly by a virus).

For DNS, [this](https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+check+DNS+settings+on+Windows+7) is a good guide - follow the "off campus" section.

For Proxy, check [this](http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/internet-connection-problem-part-iii/).

Either of these things being misconfigured can hijack your connection, possibly redirecting it via a malicious server that may evesdrop on your connection.